# How to keep MediaPlayer going no matter what

Tags: android, memory, android-mediaplayer

So I've been working on a music player for Android and I've run into a problem I'm having trouble fixing. When the user starts a song, I store the currently playing song in a public variable in my "Player" class. This is used to determine what song to play next, among other things.

The problem is that the app sometimes crashes when the user opens a lot of other memory intensive apps. The MediaPlayer stops playing, and the reference to the currently playing song is lost. I'm pretty sure this happens because these other apps claim the memory that my app was using.

My question is: **How can I make sure the MediaPlayer always keeps on playing?** The standard Android music player doesn't seem to have this problem so it should definitely be possible to keep it playing at all times somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is host the MediaPlayer in a foreground Service.